# Mailing list with user registeration

Tags: php, mailing-list

Is there any php open source script which allows different users to register and after login they can create their own mailing list with Emails and then send emails to mailing list.

Please let me know if you know such kind of script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) which you can set up on your server.

Comment: Thanks Lobster, However i am looking for some PHP script. Mailman is in python.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps PHP List is what you need:
http://www.phplist.com/details